# Unlimited changes to get an equal array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

To clarify at the outset, this is not a homework, I was asked this question at a recent interview and drew a blank.
So I've the following array,

```
{1, 6, 3, 2, 9}
```

A change is step which increments any element by 1 and decrements any other element by 1. Thus 1 change could be like,

```
{2, 5, 3, 2, 9}
```

I'm allowed to make unlimited such changes, till I get maximum number of equal elements, thus the given array could become

```
{3, 3, 3, 3, 7} or {3, 4, 4, 4, 4}
```

Beyond this point more changes will not get any more elements equal. The question is thus, making unlimited changes, what is the maximum number of elements that can be made equal.
Thus the answer for the above array is `4`. (Note there are two cases, in either case though the answer is 4)
Another example will be the array,

```
{1, 4, 1}
```

In which case we can make changes to get to

```
{2, 2, 2}
```

Thus the answer in this case is `3`.
Can someone help me with an approach to get started. I'm still drawing a blank.

Comment: Down voter your argument. More importantly can you provide an approach in pseudo-code before down voting my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a mathematical problem rather than a computer related one. Since every "Change" increments one element and decrements another, the sum of all the values in the array is constant.

This means that you can get all `n` elements of the array identical if and only if the sum of all elements can be evenly divided by `n`. Otherwise one of the elements must take another value to get `n-1` equal elements.

By the way, your answers `{3, 3, 3, 3, 7}` and `{3, 4, 4, 4, 4}` (sum of 19) are not solutions to your previous state of `{1, 6, 3, 2, 9}` (sum of 21).